# Interpolating data in Python with 'fixed points'

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, spline, interpolation

I have time-series data that is periodic (and rather sinusoidal) in nature. I rephased the data based on the period so that all of the points lie between 0 and 1. You can think of this just the same as having points sampled from a sine wave from 0 to its period 2pi. Here's one typical case:

[image: phased periodic time-series data]

I have tried interpolating this data with various `scipy.interpolate` functions, e.g.:

```
>>> scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x,y)(numpy.linspace(0, 0.99, 100))
array([ 15.13403109,  15.10173144,  15.07070986,  15.04094629,
        15.01242068,  14.98511296,  14.95900308,  14.93407098,
        14.91029659,  14.88765987,  14.86614074,  14.84571915,
        14.82637504,  14.80808836,  14.79083904,  14.77460702,
        14.75937224,  14.74511465,  14.73181418,  14.71945078,
        14.70800439,  14.69745494,  14.68778239,  14.67896666,
        14.6709877 ,  14.66382545,  14.65745985,  14.65187085,
        14.64703838,  14.64294238,  14.6395628 ,  14.63687957,
        14.63487264,  14.63352194,  14.63280742,  14.63270902,
        14.63320668,  14.63428034,  14.63590994,  14.63807542,
        14.64075672,  14.64393378,  14.64758655,  14.65169496,
        14.65623896,  14.66119848,  14.66655347,  14.67228387,
        14.67836961,  14.68479064,  14.69152691,  14.69855834,
        14.70586488,  14.71342648,  14.72122306,  14.72923458,
        14.73744098,  14.74582219,  14.75435815,  14.76302882,
        14.77181411,  14.78069399,  14.78964838,  14.79865724,
        14.80770049,  14.81675809,  14.82580996,  14.83483606,
        14.84381632,  14.85273069,  14.8615591 ,  14.87028149,
        14.87887781,  14.887328  ,  14.895612  ,  14.90370974,
        14.91160117,  14.91926624,  14.92668487,  14.93383702,
        14.94070261,  14.9472616 ,  14.95349392,  14.95937952,
        14.96489834,  14.9700303 ,  14.97475537,  14.97905347,
        14.98290455,  14.98628855,  14.98918541,  14.99157507,
        14.99343747,  14.99475255,  14.99550026,  14.99566053,
        14.9952133 ,  14.99413852,  14.99241612,  14.99002605])
```

with x being, for instance (note that some of the values repeat):

```
>>> x
array([ 0.   ,  0.01 ,  0.016,  0.018,  0.024,  0.029,  0.034,  0.036,
        0.042,  0.046,  0.048,  0.053,  0.058,  0.062,  0.069,  0.071,
        0.072,  0.079,  0.083,  0.091,  0.096,  0.102,  0.102,  0.106,
        0.108,  0.111,  0.112,  0.112,  0.122,  0.131,  0.135,  0.136,
        0.137,  0.145,  0.164,  0.168,  0.172,  0.174,  0.177,  0.178,
        0.179,  0.197,  0.202,  0.205,  0.206,  0.213,  0.215,  0.222,
        0.229,  0.233,  0.235,  0.239,  0.239,  0.241,  0.248,  0.255,
        0.258,  0.259,  0.262,  0.264,  0.266,  0.267,  0.276,  0.28 ,
        0.281,  0.281,  0.285,  0.289,  0.292,  0.292,  0.294,  0.295,
        0.299,  0.304,  0.306,  0.309,  0.313,  0.317,  0.32 ,  0.32 ,
        0.335,  0.34 ,  0.341,  0.353,  0.357,  0.359,  0.364,  0.368,
        0.369,  0.369,  0.388,  0.39 ,  0.394,  0.396,  0.399,  0.401,
        0.404,  0.406,  0.407,  0.413,  0.415,  0.418,  0.423,  0.43 ,
        0.438,  0.439,  0.443,  0.445,  0.454,  0.455,  0.475,  0.478,
        0.478,  0.48 ,  0.48 ,  0.482,  0.485,  0.486,  0.488,  0.488,
        0.498,  0.498,  0.499,  0.508,  0.514,  0.525,  0.527,  0.531,
        0.535,  0.536,  0.546,  0.547,  0.551,  0.553,  0.556,  0.563,
        0.57 ,  0.579,  0.584,  0.59 ,  0.594,  0.595,  0.596,  0.606,
        0.606,  0.619,  0.628,  0.631,  0.632,  0.633,  0.638,  0.64 ,
        0.649,  0.652,  0.654,  0.655,  0.669,  0.674,  0.684,  0.688,
        0.689,  0.692,  0.697,  0.697,  0.703,  0.703,  0.703,  0.704,
        0.706,  0.715,  0.715,  0.717,  0.72 ,  0.721,  0.73 ,  0.739,
        0.746,  0.75 ,  0.751,  0.752,  0.757,  0.762,  0.766,  0.766,
        0.783,  0.785,  0.787,  0.79 ,  0.791,  0.791,  0.806,  0.809,
        0.81 ,  0.813,  0.815,  0.816,  0.816,  0.818,  0.82 ,  0.823,
        0.839,  0.849,  0.857,  0.859,  0.862,  0.864,  0.868,  0.869,
        0.875,  0.877,  0.887,  0.888,  0.893,  0.896,  0.905,  0.907,
        0.908,  0.925,  0.926,  0.936,  0.947,  0.949,  0.955,  0.957,
        0.962,  0.97 ,  0.972,  0.976,  0.979,  0.984,  0.985,  0.986,
        0.993,  1.   ])
```

and y being, for instance:

```
>>> y
array([ 15.048,  15.046,  15.046,  15.037,  15.035,  15.048,  15.034,
        15.041,  15.03 ,  15.034,  15.037,  15.04 ,  15.038,  15.028,
        14.998,  14.976,  15.012,  15.007,  14.996,  14.979,  14.922,
        14.876,  14.881,  14.931,  14.912,  14.904,  14.906,  14.897,
        14.871,  14.786,  14.778,  14.78 ,  14.782,  14.788,  14.729,
        14.735,  14.661,  14.722,  14.668,  14.657,  14.715,  14.647,
        14.607,  14.627,  14.607,  14.625,  14.619,  14.592,  14.583,
        14.596,  14.596,  14.595,  14.584,  14.593,  14.601,  14.597,
        14.605,  14.596,  14.61 ,  14.6  ,  14.582,  14.609,  14.606,
        14.619,  14.601,  14.612,  14.619,  14.612,  14.612,  14.618,
        14.619,  14.62 ,  14.62 ,  14.619,  14.633,  14.629,  14.611,
        14.62 ,  14.629,  14.618,  14.645,  14.634,  14.633,  14.644,
        14.647,  14.649,  14.67 ,  14.661,  14.658,  14.67 ,  14.667,
        14.682,  14.676,  14.675,  14.68 ,  14.67 ,  14.673,  14.676,
        14.68 ,  14.654,  14.689,  14.699,  14.694,  14.691,  14.699,
        14.703,  14.683,  14.691,  14.706,  14.703,  14.715,  14.73 ,
        14.727,  14.72 ,  14.729,  14.718,  14.712,  14.721,  14.734,
        14.722,  14.738,  14.724,  14.73 ,  14.729,  14.735,  14.751,
        14.741,  14.752,  14.753,  14.765,  14.758,  14.759,  14.766,
        14.766,  14.774,  14.774,  14.768,  14.775,  14.789,  14.788,
        14.793,  14.787,  14.783,  14.808,  14.789,  14.793,  14.804,
        14.804,  14.793,  14.805,  14.808,  14.811,  14.825,  14.816,
        14.827,  14.827,  14.827,  14.838,  14.83 ,  14.839,  14.848,
        14.844,  14.834,  14.838,  14.845,  14.861,  14.856,  14.847,
        14.853,  14.868,  14.845,  14.857,  14.859,  14.859,  14.868,
        14.853,  14.871,  14.873,  14.875,  14.893,  14.882,  14.883,
        14.884,  14.899,  14.904,  14.907,  14.909,  14.903,  14.909,
        14.909,  14.91 ,  14.911,  14.904,  14.909,  14.933,  14.923,
        14.924,  14.907,  14.928,  14.913,  14.939,  14.944,  14.946,
        14.952,  14.935,  14.946,  14.943,  14.948,  14.952,  14.957,
        14.974,  14.981,  14.967,  14.967,  14.977,  14.987,  14.97 ,
        15.013,  14.98 ,  15.011,  15.004,  15.013,  15.   ,  15.017,
        15.02 ,  15.047,  15.03 ,  15.05 ,  15.029,  15.043,  15.038,
        15.03 ,  15.042,  15.052])
```

The function should evaluate to (nearly) the same number at 0 as 1 because the underlying data is periodic (just like we would expect a function that interpolates sine to have the same value at 0 as at 2pi). However it clearly has a long left-skew and doesn't closely resemble the data near 0. The difference between the values at 0 and 1 is roughly 0.144, which is greater than the standard deviation of the data set.

Any thoughts? Can I somehow interpolate while setting fixed points, i.e. the specification that the beginning and the end of bounds should be roughly the same?

Comment: You could try `UnivariateSpline(phases, mags, s=0)` to ensure you get pure interpolation with no smoothing.

Comment: Warren: unfortunately this didn't work for me. The resulting spline returns "nan" on all input.

Comment: And in fact scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline gives the same unfortunate results.

Comment: Did you solve? I've a similar problem and I'm wandering if numpy.polyfit may work for you, too... It works using n-degree curves, but maybe you can approximate your sine-like function with a 3rd or 4th polynomial.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using numpy.polyfit.

Answer (score 2):

The `splrep` / `splev` pair of functions claim to support periodic splines, c.f. the `per` argument.

That it's not available in UnivariateSpline is a bug. Here's a minimal implementation (but it's probably best not to use this, as accessing `_data` might not be backward compatible):

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline, splrep

class PeriodicUnivariateSpline(UnivariateSpline):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w=None, bbox=[None]*2, k=3, s=0):
        #_data == x,y,w,xb,xe,k,s,n,t,c,fp,fpint,nrdata,ier
        tck, fp, ier, msg = splrep(x, y, k=k, w=w, xb=bbox[0], xe=bbox[1],
                                   s=s, per=1, full_output=1)
        self._data = (x,y,w,bbox[0],bbox[1],k,s,len(tck[0]),tck[0],tck[1],
                      fp,None,None,ier)
        self._reset_class()
```

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. Can you explain a bit how to use it? I get a bunch of errors when I call it with just the arguments of x and y, and the resulting spline returns 0 for all input. Also, when I try to just call splrep with my data, I get ValueError: Error on input data. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you think it matters that some X values are repeated? In other words, multiple points with the same X coordinate are in the data. For example, (0.102, 14.996) as well as (0.102, 14.979) are both in the data.

Comment: With repeated points, I get an error message: `The following conditions
must hold: xb<=x[0]<x[1]<...<x[m-1]<=xe`, i.e., repeated points are not allowed. Apparently a FITPACK restriction. You probably need to use `np.unique` to deal with them.

Comment: I changed it so that there are no repeated points. However the resulting spline gives nonsense answers when evaluated between 0 and 1. The results seem to vary randomly between -5000 and 5000 with no apparent pattern. Here's a file of what I tried: http://cs.oswego.edu/~ebelling/pus.py , do you have any more ideas? (Thanks again for helping)

Comment: your observations look much too noisy to me for interpolation. With s=0.1, I get a ragged sine curve with pus_points[0], pus_points[-1]
(14.867401700528857, 14.868547533207527). Thanks pv for the recipe, I didn't know the splines in scipy have a periodic option.

Comment: just as a check, some x are very close together, and gradient is huge>>> (np.diff(y)/np.diff(x)).min()
-7299999.9937114744
>>> (np.diff(y)/np.diff(x)).max()
4700000.0024739318
>>> np.diff(x).min()
9.9999999392252903e-09

Comment: That is true: I prevented the points from repeating by adding a small epsilon to every repeated phase. However I disagree that the observations are too noisy for interpolation. I have successfully interpolated it with both splines and Fourier decomposition in other languages (and in fact Excel does a decent polynomial fit). Here is an image of the curve: http://i.imgur.com/LAVE9.png

Comment: @EarlBellinger: ok, so it seems [FITPACK](http://www.netlib.org/dierckx/) has problems generating splines for points that are close together (in general, I've not been too impressed how FITPACK often performs, and have considered replacing it with something else). You can work around this by using a suitable smoothing parameter --- `s=len(y) * 0.02**2` seems to work. (Note that you need to replace `s=0` with `s=s` in PeriodicUnivariateSpline.) Here, 0.02 is the assumed standard deviation of noise in the data.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work either. The resulting spline is a constant function that evaluates on all input to roughly the mean of y.

Comment: Works for me on the data set you give above. You probably need to reduce `s` to make the spline less stiff.

Comment: with s=0.15, I get https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/0YnsV6Ad6MlixKNfYW-g0dMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink terminology: this is a smoothing spline, not interpolation

Answer (score 1):

I think that for this application, you would be better off *fitting* some curve to your data rather than *interpolating*  it.

Interpolating works well when you have a series of sparse points that you believe to be representative of the true function, but you don't have the ability or the resources to determine more points in-between those. For example, if you had some very expensive computation that you knew to be periodic in nature with a period of 1 second, and you knew that the true function follows some kind of spline pattern, you could run the computation at 20 data points along the period, and then append the 0th value to the end of your array (the first and last values should be equal to each other when interpolating periodic data, since the last value is not actually used). `scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y, rep=True)` would be perfect for this scenario, which is actually what led me to this post! `scipy.interpolate` has lots of methods that are applicable to these scenarios.

On the other hand, fitting is best used when you have lots of data points that may be noisy. These points may not be taken sequentially (you may even have multiple points sampled at the same x-value), so interpolating between them doesn't make sense, because we aren't confident that any one point is representative of the true function, but we believe that *all* of the data, considered corporately, could give us a good idea of what the true function is. Fitting would say, roughly, "I have some model function with a number of parameters I can tweak... how can I *optimize* those parameters to best match the data I have?" The definition of "best match" is subjective, but a common one is the model that minimizes the sum of the squares of the error values between each sample point and the model function. `scipy.optimize` can help you here.